# Web development testing - view website without all my fonts installed?

Tags: windows, fonts, web-development

Im developing a website locally on my PC. As part of my testing I want to view the website how it will appear to most PC users, who wont have that many fonts installed (see http://www.typetester.org/). However my issue that I do have many fonts installed on my machine.

How can I view the website as if these fonts weren't installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install something like VirtualBox ( https://www.virtualbox.org/ ) on your host or simply download some Linux Live CD and boot into this and have a look at your site from that live system.